# SSAS Tabular Cube Size ( Business Key)

Tags: powerbi, ssas, olap-cube, ssas-tabular, cardinality

We've build a tabular cube in our company.We're using business keys to build relationship between fact and dimension tables.

We have over 2+ billion data on cube.Especially one fact table has more than 2 billion rows in it.It containts products(bigint),date(int),store(bigint) keys.

Our product cardinality is high, because of that it causes too much memory usage.(4 GB) and our Cube total size is around (12gb).How can i reduce the memory usage of that column(productID) ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can change IsAvailableInMDX to false on any hidden columns and that will save some memory and processing time as described [here](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2018/07/02/isavailableinmdx-ssas-tabular/).